# Slide navigation menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation

i need to slide navigation menu As picture. in example i have `rtl` menu and five images for normal menu and five images(sprite) for hover/click menu.

1- if user `hover` image1 of menu slide images and show descraption of image1. (using CSS)

2 - if user `mouseover` image1 of menu slide images and show descraption of image1. (using Jquery/animated effect)

What better way to do it? CSS? Jquery ? CSS+JQUERY? any example/help codes?

normal : [IMAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EwP7.png)

when Hover & click : [IMAGE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRUyP.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need an accordion menu.

Here are some sites with demos and examples:

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-accordion-menus-tutorials/

This one is a horizontal accordion that's open source:
http://designreviver.com/tutorials/jquery-examples-horizontal-accordion/

and Code Candyon (I think they are a paid one):
http://codecanyon.net/item/classic-accordion/140404?ref=1stwebdesigner